# How to simplify a sum for the total cost of a yearly payment including compound interest

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-sum

I want to simplify the below sum for the total cost over a yearly payment including compound interest over *n* years.

An example: we have 150 euros that need to be paid every year and an interest of 2%. The total cost over 10 years of this is the following sum (in euros):

$150+150*1.02^1+150*1.02^2+150*1.02^3+150*1.02^4+150*1.02^5+150*1.02^6+150*1.02^7+150*1.02^8+150*1.02^9 = 1642.45$

I don't see how I can simplify this sum (and then make a formula) for this. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: This is a geometric progression

Comment: Factor $150$ and notice a geometric progression

Comment: series of the form a, ar, ar^2,... are called geometric series and sum upto n terms =a (r-1)/(r^n -1)

Comment: Thank you. I see it now. :) $150*(1-1.02^{10})/(1-1.02) = 1642.45$. And in a formula: $a(1-(1+r)^n)/(1-(1+r))$ where $a$ is the yearly amount, $n$ the amount of years and $r$ the rate.